# Django - How to access POST data in GET method part of a view without saving the data in the database?

Tags: django, django-views

I have something like:

```
    def my_view(request):
       if request.method == POST
           #upload a json file and parse data from it
           parsed_data = parser.parse()
       else:
           #define some forms and variables
       context = {
           'parsed_data' = !what do I put here??!
       }
       return render(request, 'file.html', context=context)
```

What shoud I put in the context? If method is GET, parsed_data will not exist, if it is POST, parsed_data will exist but won't go to db. How do I keep its value without storing it in db?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, the template code is asking you to parse some json data if the method is POST. If it is not, maybe it can be GET or PUT then you need to write some code which is some sort of form controlling. Then the context will be that you want to return to your template.

For example, you can take my project's one function>>>

```
def create_auctions(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login_view"), {"message": "Please login to create an auction."})
        user = request.user
        title = request.POST['title']
        description = request.POST['description']
        image_url = request.POST['image_url']
        category = request.POST['category']
        starting_bid = request.POST['starting_bid']
        created = AuctionList.objects.create(user=user,title=title,description=description,image_url=image_url,category=category,starting_bid=starting_bid)
        created.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html")
```

Here user, title, description all are context

If you carefully look context is out of else statement. This means you only need to add the parsed data in the context dictionary that you got from the POST Method. For your code in 'parsed_data' it will be parsed_data like the below>>>

```
def my_view(request):
       if request.method == POST
           #upload a json file and parse data from it
           parsed_data = parser.parse()
       else:
           #define some forms and variables
       context = {
           'parsed_data' = parsed_data
       }
       return render(request, 'file.html', context=context)
```